# Saber a posição em uma listagem

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo, query

Estou usando essa *query* para saber quantidade de comentários de um usuário:

```
$comentarios = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM topicos_comentarios WHERE autor='".$ver['autor']."'")->rowCount();
```

Porém, gostaria de saber qual a posição dele no ranking geral, eu fiz um teste e consegui listar todos os usuários e suas posições com esse código:

```
<?php
include 'assets/php/config.php';
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM topicos_comentarios GROUP BY autor ORDER BY count(autor) DESC");
$i = 1;
  while($ver = $ranking->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $comentarios = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM topicos_comentarios WHERE autor='".$ver['autor']."'")->rowCount();
?>
<?php echo $i; ?>°- <?php echo $ver['autor'];?> - <?php echo $comentarios; ?></br>
<?php ++$i; } ?>
```

Mas como eu poderia obter essa posição individualmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estiver usando PostgreSQL, por exemplo, não é necessária essa função on php e dá pra escrever um SQL que retorna só o autor que tu quer, com o ranking e número de comentários. Com este SQL:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER(), g.autor, g.n FROM (SELECT count(tc.autor) as n, tc.autor FROM topicos_comentarios tc GROUP BY autor ORDER BY n DESC) g WHERE autor='nome do autor'
```

Como não sei qual o backend tu está usando, escrevi um exemplo considerando só o ANSI SQL. Onde vais ter que procurar o autor no código php mesmo. Com a diferença de trazer todos os autores com as quantidades de comentários em uma consulta só, com a fetchAll().

```
<?php
include 'assets/php/config.php';

function autorRank($autor, $allRes) {
    foreach ($allRes as $rank => $umRes)
        if ($umRes["autor"] == $autor) return array ($rank + 1, $umRes["n"]);
}



$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT g.autor, g.n FROM (SELECT count(tc.autor) as n, tc.autor FROM topicos_comentarios tc GROUP BY autor ORDER BY n DESC) g");

$all = $ranking->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ret = autorRank("nome do autor", $all);
$i = $ret[0];
$comentarios = $ret[1];

?>
<?php echo $i; ?>°- <?php echo "nome do autor";?> - <?php echo $comentarios; ?></br>
```

Comment: Retornou os seguintes erros: Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias in C:\Xamp\htdocs\aGabriel\list.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\Xamp\htdocs\aGabriel\list.php on line 14

Comment: parece q o MySQL precisa de alias, então deve ficar "SELECT tc.autor, tc.n FROM (SELECT count(autor) as n, autor FROM topicos_comentarios tc GROUP BY autor ORDER BY n DESC) a" mas eu não tenho fácil um MySQL pra testar aqui.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! :D